# Spring security logout invalidates session scope object which is not required

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC, Data, Security application. When a user logs out I lose some client's data which is stored in Session Scope object ( /login?logout )

`@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`

Does anybody know how to prevent spring security not to remove data stored in some particular session scope object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java config:

```
.logout()
  .invalidateHttpSession(false);
```

XML:

```
<logout invalidateHttpSession="false">
```